# Does an exponential model fit my data?

Tags: time-series, biostatistics

I am measuring accumulation of a fluorescent-tagged protein at a particular location within a cell over time. In previous experiments that I have performed, I see a standard exponential distribution where the fluorescence intensity reaches a plateau, however in my current experiment, I see a distribution as shown below:

[image]

What is the best model to use for this data? Should I use two separate exponential models, one for the increase in intensity up to the peak and one for the decay phase, or is there another statistical model for this type of distribution. Thanks!

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish with the model? Do you want to have a parameter to summarize the data and conduct inference? Or do you want to find the curve? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Typically, when we have a standard exponential distribution, we find the curve that fits the data (average of several replicates) best, and calculate a half life for the change in intensity, as well as diffusion coefficient and statistics (chi-squared)

Comment: There are a wide variety of functions that might fit this shape. Where possible subject-area understanding of the processes should inform the choice. Just picking something that looks to fit well enough may not be as useful.

Comment: For simply fitting a curve, you could use a non parametric smoother, say a spline or a loess model. For the rest, I am afraid I lack the substantive background to understand it (perhaps you can provide more info to that end, like what is a diffusion coefficient and what chi-square statistic are you interested in, or what is a half life for the change of intensity?). Is this something you can derive from a smoothed curve (I guess for the half life it should be possible)?

Comment: A pair of exponentials will provide a not-terrible fit, but the problem (as often with such models) is a nasty ridge in the parameter space, and difficulty with getting an actually good fit. [This fit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/95UPN.png) is about as good as can be done, I think, but I don't think you'll find the parameters at all interpretable, and other models should fit quite well.

Comment: The first part of the curve looks parabolic, and then it dips off toward an asymptote (I'm assuming this is horizontal, but the picture does not extend far enough to the right for me to be sure).  So how about something like this? $$\big(-a(x-b)^2+c\big)e^{-d(x-f)}+g$$

Answer (score 2):

I echo @glen_b 's comment. Don't just fit random functions, think about it. What causes the signal to rise and fall? Examples:

rate of transcription

rate of translation

rate of transport

percent transported to your region

rate of degradation

Is quenching of the signal occurring due to high concentration, incorporation into a complex?

Is the protein denaturing for some reason (lysozomes?) thus affecting the signal?

Are there a plausible negative/positive feedbacks occurring?

What are you normalizing to? Are you sure this isn't rising after ~ 2minutes?

What is new about this time? This seems to be an important hint.

Also many curves people fit are artifacts of averaging, there is a long history of people complaining of this in the learning literature. The correct thing to do is fit a curve to each time-series that has been derived from assumptions that people in your field will find acceptable. There is currently not enough info in your question to provide a reasonable answer. You have a nice smooth curve here, don't miss the opportunity to solve it with a series of differential equations.

Comment: Thanks for the great comments. The data is double normalized, first the region of interest (ROI) is normalized to the "pre-condition" ROI intensity, and then this is normalized to the total cellular intensity to account for photobleaching. The timescale that we are looking at here (<5 min) transcription and translation should be really quite negligible, and so (at least in the recruitment phase) this should be transport of the protein. What is new about this time is that we are looking at a different (unrelated) protein, hence different dynamics. It just happens to be a similar technique.

Comment: @Josh The peak is ~2x the plateau which seems like a hint. Perhaps the protein is dimerizing. A quick search indicates the florescence of GFP is suppressed by dimerization, which is a function of concentration: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8578587